# What is the average of rolling two dice and only taking the value of the higher dice roll?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I am referencing to this question on mathunderflow:
[What is the average of rolling two dice and only taking the value of the higher dice roll?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223238/what-is-the-average-of-rolling-two-dice-and-only-taking-the-value-of-the-higher)

Now I tried:

```
Mean[Max[DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 6}], DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 6}]]]
```

and

```
Mean[Max[DiscreteUniformDistribution[{{1, 6}, {1, 6}}]]]
```

but both only give me the wrong answer $\frac{7}{2}$.

What shall I do to get the right result:$$E[X] = \sum_{x=1}^6\frac{2(x-1)+1}{36}x = \frac{1}{36}\sum_{x=1}^6(2x^2 - x) = \frac{161}{36} \approx 4.47$$

Comment: `N@Mean[Max /@ Tuples[Range@6, 2]]`

Comment: I assume you want some kind of simulation of the problem rather than the analytic solution you already have. With a couple of changes to your code `N[Mean[Table[
   Max[RandomVariate[DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 6}]], 
    RandomVariate[DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 6}]]], {1000}]]]`

Comment: @CameronMurray: Thank you, this is helpful, yet I really want the analytic solution since I want to play around with it.

Comment: I thought this was an interesting question so I wrote a quick script in python to calculate the answer, if anyone is familiar with the language: http://pastebin.com/egvQD3W8

Comment: @Decency No, I don't think anybody has heard of Python before :-).  Did you know this is a *Mathematica* site?

Comment: @whuber Yeah, but I don't really know what that entails. That's why I posted a comment, not an answer. :D This question popped up in the top left under "Hot Questions" and I like probability stuff.

Comment: @Decency Since you like contributing Python solutions to probability questions, please consider hanging out on [the stats site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is possible to do the calculation analytically in Mathematica as well. Here's one way to define the desired distribution:

```
 maxDist = 
   TransformedDistribution[Max[x, y], 
           {x \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 6}], 
            y \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 6}]}];
```

Then the mean is calculated

```
 Mean[maxDist]
```

which is the desired 4.47222.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I wanted. Why do you think would my method not work? Or posed differently: When to use TransformedDistribution and when not?

Comment: @vonjd: `Max[a,b]` normally remains unevaluated for distributions, but in your method `Max[a,a]` simplifies to `a`, regardless of whether `a` is a number. Effectively, you're taking the mean of one die roll. In this answer, `x` and `y` have the same distribution, but are different objects.

Answer (score 16):

You could create the TransformedDistribution described by bill s or you could use Mathematica's built in `OrderDistribution` command, which addresses precisely the sort of problem you have posed.

```
Mean[OrderDistribution[{DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 6}], 2}, 2]]//N
(* 4.47222 *)
```

Comment: Why is `k==2` in this case?

Answer (score 14):

For your amusement, **here is a cute, *Mathematica*-oriented solution:** represent the die by its probabilities and "teach" the software to combine results using the maximum.  So, to begin, here's a way to create dice and an example of the usual six-sided fair die:

```
Clear[x]; die[n_] = Sum[x[i]/n, {i, n}];
die[6]
```

> $\frac{x[1]}{6}+\frac{x[2]}{6}+\frac{x[3]}{6}+\frac{x[4]}{6}+\frac{x[5]}{6}+\frac{x[6]}{6}$

The arguments to `x` are the possible values and the coefficients in such a sum are their probabilities.  Now for the "lessons":

```
x /: Times[n_x, m_x] := x[Max[Sequence @@ n, Sequence @@ m]];
x /: Power[n_x, m_Integer] := n;
expectation[y_, f_: Identity] := Expand[y] /. x -> f;
```

The first is the instruction to retain the larger of two values when combining `x`'s via `Times` (as is conventional); the second states that when multiple `x`'s are combined (via `Power`) the maximum does not change; and the third is the definition of expectation (when applied to an object like `die[6]`, anyway).  The optional argument `f` is a function whose expectation is requested; by default, it's the expectation of the die's values themselves.

To make these workings evident--they can seem mysterious in practice--let's first show the combination of two dice.  It can be done with a multiplication (but keep reading--there are problems with this approach):

```
die[6] * die[6] // Expand
```

> $\frac{x[1]}{36}+\frac{x[2]}{12}+\frac{5 x[3]}{36}+\frac{7 x[4]}{36}+\frac{x[5]}{4}+\frac{11 x[6]}{36}$

This indicates, for instance, there is a $7/36$ chance that the largest of two independently thrown fair dice is $4$.  Finally, the expectation:

```
die[6] * die[6] // expectation
```

> $\frac{161}{36}$

By the way, you can use powers to combine multiple identical dice.  Want the expectation of the largest when rolling three dice?

```
die[6]^3 // expectation
```

> $\frac{119}{24}$

What if we were to cap the largest value at $5$?

```
expectation[die[6]^3, Min[5, #] &]
```

> $\frac{245}{54}$

What about the expected value from the largest of throwing two d10's and a d12?

```
die[10]^2 * die[12] // expectation
```

*Don't try this!*  It will take too long to complete.  *Apparently `Expand` (as invoked in `expectation`) suffers from some terribly bad inefficiency.*  To work around this, use `Outer` to implement the addition and multiplication that before I had taken for granted:

```
combine[a_, b_] := Outer[Times, a, b];             (* Multiplies and expands *)
combine[a_, b_, c__] := combine[a, combine[b, c]]; (* Iterates across multiple arguments *)
multiply[a_, n_Integer] /; n >= 1 := Nest[combine[a, #] &, a, n - 1] (* Replaces `Power` *)
```

Now things are fine:

```
combine[multiply[die[10], 2], die[12]] // expectation // AbsoluteTiming
```

> $\left\{0.0040003,\frac{137}{16}\right\}$